# API calls getting counted while hitting from local in sanity

Tags: next.js, next.js13, sanity

I'm using sanity + nextjs13 and fetching data using next-sanity. But the API calls are being made to the hosted server, which is counting under the free limit of 10k. How to prevent this counting while I am fetching from local?